# Difference between $V^P$ and $V[G]$

Tags: set-theory, forcing

This may be a basic question.  I am studying forcing at Kunen's book. However, in several other papers that I am reading, they use that something is true in $V^P$ instead of $V[G]$. I know that if $V[G]\models \varphi((\tau_1)_G,\ldots, (\tau_n)_G)$, by the Truth Lemma, there is $p\in G$ such that $p\Vdash(\tau_1,\ldots, t_n)$. However, I think that what they mean with $\varphi$  is true in $V^P$, is that $\mathbb 1_P\Vdash\varphi(\tau_1,\ldots,\tau_n)$.

So let

(1) There is $p\in G$ such that $p\Vdash \varphi$.

(2) $\mathbb 1_P\Vdash\varphi$.

Obviously, (2) implies (1), since $\mathbb 1_P$ always belong to $G$.  However, I cannot see that they are equivalent. My first question is: are they really equivalent?

And my second question, which is the motivation of all this, given a partial order $P$, what does it really mean $P$ forces $\varphi$? Does it mean  (1) or (2) in the case they are not equivalent? Above all, I would like that a forcing P that I am building really forces a formula $\varphi$. However, I would like to say this as a formula of just $V$ (i.e., something like $"V\models P$ forces $\varphi"$, so I cannot mention $G$). However, if the "real" definition of $P$ forces $\varphi$ is (1), I do not know how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is often the case that one works with lots of notions of forcing at once (lots = more than one, but usually more than two and sometimes there are several models to work with as well), in which case it becomes much easier to use $V^P$ rather than $V[G]$, as it saves us the need to track which generic filter comes from where.

So when we write $V^P\models\ldots$ we really mean that $V[G]\models\ldots$ where $G$ is a $P$-generic filter over $V$.

---

For example, suppose that you have an elementary embedding $j\colon V\to M$ and $P\in V$ is a forcing, then $j(P)\in M$ is a forcing. Now you want to talk about $V[G]$ and $M[H]$ where $H$ is $j(P)$-generic over $M$. Instead it's much easier to talk about $V^P$ and $M^{j(P)}$.

(I was generally against this sort of abuse of the notation, but recently I sat in a course about forcing, large cardinals and combinatorial properties of small cardinals. After just two weeks it became apparent how superior this is to $V[G]$ notation in most cases.)

---

**Addition with respect to the comments.**

We can define forcing internally and externally. The external definition is simple, $p\Vdash\varphi$ if for every generic filter $G$ such that $p\in G$ it is true that $V[G]\models\varphi$.

Now it is also true that if $V[G]\models\varphi$ then there is $p\in G$ such that $p\Vdash\varphi$. Otherwise every element in $G$ does not force $\varphi$, but since $\{q\in P\mid q\Vdash\varphi\lor q\Vdash\lnot\varphi\}$ is dense, there is some $p\in G$ deciding the truth value of $\varphi$, so there must be one forcing $\lnot\varphi$. So $V[G]$ cannot satisfy $\varphi$.

The above is easily shown from the internal definition of the forcing relation.

Therefore it is true that $V[G]\models\varphi$ if and only if there exists $p\in G$ such that $p\Vdash\varphi$.

Now if we require that for *every* generic $G$, then $1_P$ forces $\varphi$, because it appears in *every* generic filter $G$.

Comment: Yes, thanks, that makes sense. However, I would like then to know how to write $V\models "P$ forces $\varphi"$. I cannot say $V\models \exists p\in G(p\Vdash \varphi)$, since $G\notin V.$ How would it be a correct way to say it?

Comment: The correct way would be $1_P\Vdash\varphi$. Remember that the forcing relation has an internal definition as well by induction on the complexity of the formula $\varphi$ (it's a long definition, but you definitely find it in Kunen's book).

Comment: Sure, the forcing relation does not make me troubles for the moment to define it in $V$, or too much troubles that I just take it as a black box. My point is that then these two notions (1) and (2) defined above are not equivalent, and to prove (2) is stronger than (1). However, I have this doubt that whenever I would like to show that  a forcing $P$ forces $\varphi$, but only a proof in $V$, maybe to show (2) is too much, so I wonder if there is an equivalent version of (1) that can be defined only in $V$.

Comment: Yes, they are not equivalent. Consider $P$ the Cohen forcing, $\dot c$ the canonical name for the Cohen real, then there is a condition $p$ such that $p$ forces $\check 2\in\dot c$, but $1_P$ cannot force something like that. When we say "$P$ forces $\varphi$" we say *by definition* that every condition in $P$ forces $\varphi$, which is the same as $1_P$ forces $\varphi$.

Comment: @NadiaGirondo It's worth pointing out, though, that it is common for forcing arguments (at least the ones that one sees when first learning forcing) to prove not only that $\varphi$ holds in $V[G]$ but that $\varphi$ holds in any $V[H]$ for an arbitrary generic $H$; this is basically what "$P$ forces $\varphi$ means.

Comment: Thank you, @Miha, for adding this very relevant comment!

Comment: Thanks both of you guys. Then  my question is still this: Given a formula in the language of forcing $\varphi$,  is there a way of defining in $V$, that for every $G$ generic there is $p\in G$ such that $p\Vdash \varphi$? I would not want to go outside $V$ to say that. As we have discussed, saying that $\mathbb 1_P\Vdash \varphi$ is enough, but I would like to see  if there is something equivalent, and definable just in $V$.

Comment: @Nadia: But $1_P\Vdash\varphi$ **is** definable in $V$.

Comment: Of course $1_P\Vdash \varphi$ is definable in $V$, and it implies that for  every $P$-generic set $G\subseteq P$, there is $p\in G$ such that $p\Vdash \varphi$. My question is: Is there a way to say "for every generic set $G$ $P$-generic, there is $p\in G$ such that $p\Vdash \varphi$" just definable in $V$?

Comment: @NadiaGirondo Saying that for every generic $G$ we have $V[G]\vDash \varphi$ is precisely saying $1\Vdash\varphi$. This is because (assuming the poset is reasonable) for any condition $p$ there is a generic containing $p$.

Comment: @Nadia: We know that if there is $p\in G$ such that $p\Vdash\varphi$ then $V[G]\models\varphi$. Therefore you are trying to say "Every generic extension satisfies $\varphi$" which is the same as saying $1_P\Vdash\varphi$.

Comment: Ok, great. This is the equivalence that I was more or less looking for.  A priori, I do not see why if every generic $G$ there is $p\in G$ which forces $\varphi$, then $1\Vdash \varphi.$  Besides, if it is true, after the comment of @MihaHabič, if there is ONE $G$ generic, where $V[G]\models\varphi$, then $V[H]\models\varphi$ for arbitrary generic $H$. And finally, by your last arguments of Miha and Asaf, $1\Vdash \varphi$. However, it contradicts the argument of Asaf about the Cohen real above.

Comment: @Nadia: It doesn't contradict that. The fact that $1$ *doesn't* force $\check 2\in\dot c$ doesn't translate that it forces the opposite. On the other hand, $p$ as in my comment about Cohen forcing does not reside within *every* generic filter.

Comment: @Nadia: I've added to my answer about that.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Regarding the last sentence of your edit, it's not just that $1$ appears in every generic, it's that no other condition does (again, assuming the poset is sufficiently nice).

Comment: @AsafKaragila Let me see if I get:  if it is for every generic set, then in particular $\{1_P\}$ is a generic filter, right? Of course it is trivially a filter, but I do not know if it intersects every dense set.  Or what is the argument?

Comment: @Nadia: No. But if it is true for every generic filter, then it is true that every generic filter such that $1_P\in G$ satisfies $V[G]\models\varphi$. Therefore by the external definition of the forcing relation, $1_P\Vdash\varphi$.

Comment: Now I am a little bit confused. After Asaf, I understand that it is enough that if  for every generic $G$, $V[G]\models \varphi$, then $1_P\Vdash \varphi$ ($1_P\in G$ always I think since $G$ is a filter). However Miha seems to suggest that for MOST of the non-patological forcing notions. @Miha, would you have a  sufficient condition for this? or do I have to prove that in every particular case of a poset $P$ the intersection of ALL of its generic sets is just $\{1_P\}$?

Comment: @Nadia: No, Miha said that when you just start with forcing, then *usually* it is the case that the statement that you are interested in are forced by $1_P$. It is not necessarily the case in more advanced situation.

Comment: I take back my comment on Asaf's edit. I was thinking of weird cases, like if $P$ has a single coatom or something, and I confused myself.

Comment: In any case, I still cannot follow still the point why $1_P\Vdash\varphi$ if for every generic $G$ we have $V[G]\Vdash \varphi$. It looks that it must be true, and that it should not be difficult to prove.  I think that for every filter $G$, it is always the case that $1_P$. I cannot see why then, as Asaf suggests,   the external definition of the forcing relation implies $1_P\Vdash \varphi$.

Comment: @Naida: **Every** generic filter includes $1_P$. Now read the definition of the forcing relation again. If you don't know the internal definition, perhaps read that definition and be sure that you understand it.

Comment: Of course $1_P$ is always in  $G$, that is why I did not understand your comment when you said "every generic filter such that $1_P\in G$ satisfies $V[G]\models \varphi$", since it seemed to imply it is not always the case.

Comment: Regarding the internal definition, I am  not sure which one  you meant. I assume you are talking about, for example, Definition 3.3 in Chapter VII of Kunen's book, which is a definition by recursion and definable in $V$. I do not see here any problem to understand it. However, I do not see neither for the moment how it can help.

Comment: Ok, I think finally I got it. I use Definition 3.1, chapter VII of Kunenś book: $p\Vdash\varphi$ if and only if for every generic $G$ with $p\in G$, we have $V[G]\models\varphi$. So in particular if every generic $G$, we have $V[G]\models\varphi$, since $1_P$ is in every generic filter, we then have $1_P\Vdash \varphi$. Thanks for your help, and your patience.

Comment: Also, if @MihaHabič could tell me any reference where it says that if $V[G]\models\varphi$ (G generic filter) then $V[H]\models\varphi$ for every generic H,  I would thank it a lot, since I have been looking around Kunen's book, and I cannot find this specific result.

Comment: @Nadia: I don't have Kunen's book in front of me, but yes. It's an inductive definition involving dense sets and whatnot. I know that I had a hard time *fully* comprehending it until about when I wrote my M.Sc. thesis two years ago. The reason this definition helps here is that it's easy (or easier?) to show that for any given sentence (or formula with a fixed assignment of names) the set of conditions which force it, or force its negation is dense. And I used that argument in my answer...

Comment: @NadiaGirondo I think you might have misunderstood my comment, and I'm sorry if I confused you. I was only trying to say that one often argues like: "Let $G$ be generic. blah blah blah. Therefore $V[G]$ satisfies something." where the blah blah blah part doesn't make any further assumptions on $G$. The conclusion of the argument then holds for an arbitrary generic and thus the "something" property is actually forced by 1.